# Guidance to create a machine learning alg to find multiple overlapping date over multiple period

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, supervised-learning, beginner

i have a dataset of work period from a lot of people during multiple years and i would like to find the overlapping date between these periods, the data would look something like this:

```
Name;Start;End;Valid
John Doe;2015-01-01;2017-01-01;Yes
Jonh Doe;2016-02-03;2016-06-04;No
Jane Doe;1980-01-01;2018-01-01;Yes
```

As you can see i can have multiple lines for the same person and are mapped as valid or not, there are a few more rules like if the person is a professor he can have overlapping work periods but the core is to find these wrong periods created by human error.

Since i am a beginner in machine learning i would to try to implement this as a learning project although i intend to use and expand in the future if all goes well, at least to my eyes seems like a somewhat easy task to do.

I would like your opinion in what kind of algorithm i should use, or what framework i should or not use, or even if this is not very cost effective to implement on ML.

I thought of somekind of supervised learning using tensorflow, maybe is too much?

Also any tips, tricks or tutorials would be much appreciate it.

**EDIT: More Information**
At first i am providing the answer, which would be the "Yes" or "No" on Valid, but when i provide something like:

```
Row;ID;Name;Start;End;
1;1;John Doe;2015-01-01;2017-01-01;
2;1;Jonh Doe;2016-02-03;2016-06-04;
3;1;Jonh Doe;2017-06-02;2018-04-01;
4;1;Jonh Doe;1990-01-01;2017-07-01;
```

So i would like it to point out, hey, John Doe has 2 invalid periods, row 2 and 4, **why should it give me that?** because 2016-02-03 to 2016-06-04 is already covered by row 1 and row 4 overlap with row 1,2,3

At first i thought on making this with regular programming to check for everything, but there are some cases where human error make this quite a difficult task to do, thats why ml got in to my mind, the algorithm does not need to have really high accuracy, this is mostly a learning project.

Comment: Hi Pettrus, Can you shed some light what do you exactly mean by overlapping date between periods?(probably by adding the answer to your sample dataset)

Comment: There is not a proper answer but more like it pointing out to me invalid periods, i tried my best to give you more information on what i want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorting and cleaning this dataset from overlapping periods is a task you can do  with plain python, perhaps a bit more comfortable if you use pandas.  Machine learning would be an additional overkill, it adds more complexity and is of no help for that task. Although I understand you are looking for a learning project, I do not recommend to use this one, and rather recommend  to pick a task that is more often solved with machine learning.

Comment: I see, i guess i will find another project more related to machine learning then, thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

This is quite easy and you don't need machine learning at all.

Order by Person and Start date. Then simply iterate over each data line for a person and see if the start dates are earlier than the end dates for the previous entry. Add rules as necessary.

Comment: Yes but i like to use real problems to learn something new, but as @Frankstr said this is overkill, i am going to find another project to get started, thanks for the answer.